# Using array fetched by JQuery AJAX in materializecss' auto-complete data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, materialize

this is my first time working with materializecss, and I want to make the auto complete feature of it more dynamic by adding array of options fetched from DB but it doesn't seem to work. I did several tries on my own and search stack overflow and other forums for almost a day but could not find answer to it.

Here is the my JS:

```
    function fetchGlobalSkills(){
    var skills = [];
    $.ajax({
        url: "/skills/global",
        dataType: "json",
    }).success(function(data){
            $.each(data, function(key, value){
                $.each(value, function (key, value) {
                    skills.push(value);
                });
                console.log(JSON.stringify(value));
        });
    });
    $('input#skillSearch').on('focus', function(){
                data = [];
                skills.forEach(function () {
                    data.push(JSON.stringify(skills.skillName));
                });
        console.log(data)
    });
}

fetchGlobalSkills();
```

I know this isn't the best, but if you can understand my approach here and help me solve this, it would be great.

Also, I have checked my controller's O/P, it seems fine, for instance this is my o/p:

```
[[{"skillName":"smart"}],[{"skillName":"confident"}]]
```

Thanks for help in advance

UPDATE:

I updated the js above based on one answer, what I get here is:

`[undefined, undefined, undefined]` in data array. Expected result is:

```
data:{
    "fast": null,
    "smart": null,
}
```

So that autocorrect can use it

Answer (score 1):

Get your skills names like this...

```js
    skills = [];//creates an array
     data =[[{"skillName":"smart"}],[{"skillName":"confident"}]];//your data

     data.forEach(function(element,index,array){
    skills.push(element[0].skillName);
     });
     console.log(skills);
```

Comment: can I do this: `data =[$.ajax({url: '/skills/global', dataType: 'json'})];` ? to fetch data dynamically with ajax?